# Link data to gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-structures

I have a script that calculates something related to a mesh of a unity's gameobject. That information is saved into a dictionary but this info wont change for that mesh. The problem is, playing, stoping and playing again makes me recalculate that info. Is there a way to keep that dictionary like the gameobject keeps the mesh?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Why do you need code? I only want to save the dictionary persistently so even if I stop and play again I dont need to recalculate the dictionary @Bas

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without seeing what you're doing?

Comment: Because i have described my problem maybe?

Comment: You could look into serialization

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem of linking the data to an object to keep it persistent

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez why not? Run script, save dictionary to file, run script again, check if file already exists, if yes load from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to store data in Unity. I can think of these:

1. **PlayerPrefs**. The easiest way and only supports basic data types. however read and write is costly and should avoided in update methods. This can be done using `var i = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("myInt", 0)` or `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("myInt", newValue);` Mostly this can help to store user data such as current xp or number of coins and gems.
2. **Database**. maybe the most difficult way but also most efficient if working with tons of data.
3. **Serialization**. Unity uses serialization by default. it stores them as meta data in Plain Text format or Binary format or Both (your choice).
4. **JSONObject**. Most flexible, customizable, portable and reliable. This is a better replacement for Serialized data. JSONObject files should be put in StreamingAssets folder and then copy to Application DataPath. In order to make this work you need a JSONObject class (can be found on the [internet](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710)) and converters which you can write for your project to convert back and forth to/from JSONObject.

please correct me if I'm wrong.

This is my suggestion to your problem:

Make use of Unity Editor. Create a script derived from EditorWindow. Open its custom window it in your project. In that window make it so that when you select an object and click on a button, a JSONObject is generated and stored in the StreamingAssets folder. This way you have all the JSONObjects ready when your project is played or restarted.

Comment: Could you explain more  playerpref or put an example? Same with basic json object please

Comment: That would take too much time which sadly i don't have. also SO is not a place for tutorials. please search for yourself and ask code related questions here. I updated my answer to cover more information you might need

Comment: Would the last option work when running on android phone for example?

Comment: yes I use JSONObject all the time and it's just perfect for storing [non-user] data. I updated the answer again

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at playerprefs from unity it will save your data persistently